# Can Android: Netrunner be played with more than two people?

Tags: android-netrunner

I've heard that in the old CCG version of Netrunner, there were rules which allowed the game to be played with four players, similar to two-headed giant in Magic: The Gathering.

Were these rules official? How did they differ from the normal two-player rules? Do they still work in the modern LCG version of Android: Netrunner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe that there is an official 4 player variant for Android Netrunner, however the "Big Sell Out" variant from the original Netrunner has been reimplemented, unofficially:
http://anr.phtn.de/formats/ANR_BigSellOut.pdf

A bit of discussion can be found in [this thread.](http://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/67630-house-ruled-multiplayer-variants-for-original/)